# What is the security and trust model of an Opendime?

Tags: security, trust, hardware-wallet

Opendimes use some entropy on the device in combination with some entropy added by the owner to generate private keys directly on the device. Until the device's seal is broken, it is claimed to be impossible to access the private key and only the address can be learned instead.

What are the security assumptions that a user of an Opendime is making and how reasonable is it to trust the device? Are there any special attacks that a payee exposes himself to when accepting payments with an Opendime from either the creator of the device, or a payer?